# Как правильно вывести значение из БД MySQL?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, mysqli

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в проблеме. Есть запрос к БД:

```sql
INSERT INTO uvbvn_uap_referrals
SELECT null,
       0,
       '-',
       ur.parent_affiliate_id,
       0,
       concat('За ',user_login),
       'Бонусные баллы',
       '-',
       '-',
       0, 
       io.uid,
       amount_value*0.2,
       'bon',
       now(),
       2,
       0,
       0
FROM uv_ihc_orders io 
LEFT JOIN uv_users u on io.uid=u.id
LEFT JOIN uv_uap_affiliates ua on io.uid =ua.uid 
LEFT JOIN uv_uap_relations ur on ur.affiliate_id=ua.id
WHERE io.used=0 
  and io.status='Completed'
```

Все свои функции он выполняет, кроме одной. Данная часть `ur.parent_affiliate_id` выводит NULL, хотя должна выводить id. Столбец `parent_affiliate_id` в таблице `uv_uap_relations` есть. Данные в нём тоже есть. Не пойму что не так. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где ошибка?

Comment: *Данная часть ur.parent_affiliate_id выводит NULL, хотя должна выводить id.* Что есть, то и выводит. У MySQL недостаточно фантазии, чтобы гадить по-мелкому, это не Т1000. *Столбец parent_affiliate_id в таблице uv_uap_relations есть.* это очевидно, иначе была бы ошибка исполнения. *Данные в нём тоже есть.* А вот соответствующих условиям - нет, поэтому и NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что нету в этом столбце соотвествующих данных. То есть вы отправляете запрос по которому MySQL в столбце вашей таблице не находит данных, потому и прописывает там NULL. Попробуйте подкорректировать запрос данных, может быть вы где-то допустили опечатку.

Comment: Спасибо. Вы были правы. Были проблемы с отсутствием некоторых значений. Добавила правильные и всё заработало.